# How do you get nulls in strings with null-terminated strings?

Tags: string, null, null-terminated

Let's say you wanted to read in a binary file that could potentially have NULLs in it. How would you do so in a language that was NULL terminated? I guess you'd just map it to a byte array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we talk about C (and the same or similar arguments apply to C++ as well), the zero-terminated strings in this language are rather a convention and I would not say that the "language is NULL terminated". Some functions - like `strcpy` or `strlen` treat null character in a string as the terminator. Other functions - like `fread` - do not. Use documentation to see if functions you want to use treat null character specially or not.